# How to initialize a property by setting some value without passing anything over a constructor

Tags: c#

I have some additional work to do get the value from a string and set to a property As shown in the example.

Here I am putting all the logic to extract a value from a string in a **constructor** and I have set all the property.

```
public class CourseModuleView
{

    public CourseModuleView(string str)
    {
        var re = new Regex(@"'(.*?)'");
        var results = Regex.Matches(str, @"'(.*?)'", RegexOptions.Singleline)
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value);

        UserId = int.Parse(results.ElementAt(0));
        ComponentType = results.ElementAt(1);
        ModuleId = int.Parse(results.ElementAt(2));
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int ModuleId { get; set; }
    public string ComponentType { get; set; }
}
```

I am calling my constructor as:

```
//str will have the pattern like this, 
//"The user with id '2209' viewed the 'url' activity with course module id '317'
// but it will be a list of string
var modCompletedResult = allLog
     .Where(x => x.EventName == EventNameMessage.CourseModuleView)
     .Select(x => new CourseModuleView(x.str)
     {
        //other property setting code goes here

     }).ToList();
```

Sometimes if I want to inject other value in the same constructor (from the different methods) I have to pass both the unrelated value also.

What is the other most appropriate way to `set the property` while extracting the value from the `string` without writing all the logic in the constructor?

Comment: It sounds like you should probably have different constructor overloads, to handle your various use cases.

Comment: I havequestion here? will the string be always same?

Comment: @viveknuna the pattern of the string will always be the same.

Comment: You can have 2 constructors, one with no parameters, and one with the string param

Comment: Can you write the regex in the calling method?

Comment: @viveknuna yeah I can access that code.

Comment: Then write the logic there and simply pass the userid, id, memberid and so so....you can also set the default value for these

Comment: @AlvinStefanus This case can't be done without passing any parameter in the constructor?

Comment: You can write the `setter` to handle to logic, for example `public int Id { get; set { this.Id = //logic here extracting "value"; }}`, so each property will have their own logic setter.

Comment: @AlvinStefanus I have updated the code (in calling function) with the actual use case. sorry for the previous. I thought that would be the same but it gave other meanings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public int Id { get; set { this.Id = extractId(value); }}
public int UserId { get; set { this.UserId = extractUserId(value); }}
.....
```

Then assign it in the select:

```
var theString = "The user with id '2209' viewed the 'url' activity with course module id '317'.";
var modCompletedResult = allLog
 .Where(x => x.EventName == EventNameMessage.CourseModuleView)
 .Select(x => new CourseModuleView()
 {
    Id = theString,
    UserId = theString,
    ......
 }).ToList();
```

Sorry im using a phone, quite hard to write code here.

---

The C# `setter` and `getter` is powerful, you can even set other properties when assignning only one property. Example

```
public int Id { get; 
    set {   
         var extracted = extractAll(value); 
         this.Id = extracted.Id;
         this.UserId = extracted.UserId;
         .......
     } 
}

.Select(x => new CourseModuleView()
 {
    Id = theString, //assign only Id will automatically assign all properties according to the Id setter logic
 }).ToList();
```

Btw you have to keep the name `value` in the setter, if not, it will try to find the named variable inside the local scope.

---

Sorry my mistake, when you assigning property in select, it has to be the same type, `Id` should be assigned by int.

For your case, you can make a dummy property of type string then apply the setter logic in it.

Example:

```
public string dummy { get; set { ..... }}
```

---

Hope this works for you.

```
public void SetEverything(string str)
{
    var re = new Regex(@"'(.*?)'");
    var results = Regex.Matches(str, @"'(.*?)'", RegexOptions.Singleline)
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value);

    this.UserId = int.Parse(results.ElementAt(0));
    this.ComponentType = results.ElementAt(1);
    this.ModuleId = int.Parse(results.ElementAt(2));
}
public int Id { get; set; }
public int UserId { get; set; }
public int ModuleId { get; set; }
public string ComponentType { get; set; }

public string Setter { get { return ""; } //return empty string 
    set {
        SetEverything(value);
    }
}
```

Then

```
var modCompletedResult = allLog
 .Where(x => x.EventName == EventNameMessage.CourseModuleView)
 .Select(x => new CourseModuleView()
 {
    Setter = x.str,
 }).ToList();
```

Comment: is this possible `Id = theString`?

Comment: The setter logic will extract the id from theString, which you will have to implement it. I just put `extractId(value)` to illustrate. You have to implement the `extractId` function yourself. The `value` will be `theString`.

Comment: the value we passing are a string, but the property is `int`, it gave me the error, and is this syntactically correct? `public int Id { get;  set { var extracted = extractAll(value) ;}}`

Comment: `extractAll(value)` is a function that should return an object that contains the classes properties. Dont just copy my code, my code is there to give you an idea how setter and getter works, you have to implement the `extracting function` by yourself. In this case you have already made yours, which is your constructor, which separate string and assign in to your properties.

Comment: I don't know why but for some reason I got an error while running the code in debug mode and checking `modCompletedResult` using the breakpoint. the error says...the target process existed with code - `1073741819` while evaluating the function...`...Setter.get`..

Comment: Just return empty string in the getter `get { return ""; } set { ..... }`